# How to reverse arrow icon in right position when dropdown is opened? Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How to set arrow icon in left side when is dropdown opened? Default position is right but when click and open dropdown I want to show icon left. Look images example:

1. Default -> https://ibb.co/0CDrkRN
2. When click and open additional menu -> https://ibb.co/QkW9YDt

I try to example one more time:

Die Stats >

Die Stats2 >

:click on die Stats or die Stats2 :

< Die Stats

:arrow is switched in left position:

Look my code:

```
<div class="first-lower-div">
  <div class="low-lower">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-one">
                                                                                                                                            Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
                                                                                                                                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                                                                                                            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One  <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="low-lower">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-two">
                                                                                                                                            Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
                                                                                                                                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                                                                                                            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="low-lower">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-three">
                                                                                                                                            Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
                                                                                                                                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                                                                                                            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li class="item-has-children">
            <a href="#0">Main Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
              <div class="hr2"></div>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Javascript:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children");
links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('selected')) {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('selected')
    } else {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('selected')
    }
  })
})
```

Css:

```
.section-two {
    padding: 0 30px;
    .header-holder {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 40px 0px;
        h3 {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'Replica Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #666;
        }
    }
    .wrapper-two {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        .first-div-holder {
            background: brown;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .first-lower-div {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            .low-lower {
                p {
                    color: white;
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 980px) { 
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                width: 100%;
              }
        }
        .second-lower-div {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 150px;
            h1 {
                font-size: 80px;
                color: white;
            }
            h4 {
                font-size: 30px;
                margin-top: -50px;
                color: white;
            }
        }
        .third-lower-div {
            display: flex;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            text-align: right;
            justify-content: center;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            .bottom-lower {
                display: flex;
                align-content: center;
                &:nth-child(1),
                &:nth-child(2),
                &:nth-child(3),
                &:nth-child(4) {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    color: white;
                }
            }
            p {
                color: white;
                font-weight: 600;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: 0 10px;
            }
            @media (max-width: 700px) { 
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                width: 100%;
              }
        }
        .second-div-holder {
            background: #f1f1f1; 
            .second-div-holder-div {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: center;
                padding: 15px; 
                .div-column {
                    flex: 1;
                    min-width: 30%;
                    padding: 25px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    // for small device 
                    // flex: 0 0 100%;
                    // max-width: 100%;
                    @media (max-width: 600px) {  
                        min-width: 100%!important;
                      }
                      @media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 600px)  {  
                        min-width: 50%!important;
                      }

                    .div-column-first {
                        height: 210px;
                        img {
                            height: 100%;
                            width: 100%;
                            object-fit: cover;
                        }
                        #first-child-image {
                            border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
                        }
                        #second-child-image {
                            border-bottom: 5px solid red;
                        }
                        #third-child-image {
                            border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
                        }
                    }
                    .div-column-second {
                        padding: 40px;
                        background: white;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    .dropbtn {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 55px;
        background: #153161;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
        padding: 12px 50px;

        i {
            margin-left: 30px;
            color: #8391ab;
        }
        .arrow {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 6px solid transparent;
            border-right: 6px solid transparent;
            border-top: 6px solid #8191aa;
            margin: 100%;
            padding-top: 4px;
            z-index: 999;
        }
    }
    .dropbtn-two {
        background: red;
    }
    .dropbtn-three {
        background: yellow;
    }
}

.dropdown-content {

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 330px;
    z-index: 999;
    a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 25px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        &:hover {
            background-color: #F8F8F8
        }
    }
    .rightt { 
            display: inline-block;
            // width: 9px;
            // height: 9px;
            cursor: pointer;
            // padding-left: 180px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            z-index: 999;
            &:after {
                content: '';
                display: inline-block;
                width: 9px;
                height: 9px;
                border-top: 0.2em solid #ababab;
                border-right: 0.2em solid #ababab;
                -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
            } 
    }
    .left {

            display: inline-block;
            // width: 9px;
            // height: 9px;
            cursor: pointer;
            // padding-left: 180px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            z-index: 999;
            &:after {
                content: '';
                display: inline-block;
                width: 29px;
                height: 29px;
                border-top: 0.2em solid #ababab;
                border-right: 0.2em solid #ababab;
                -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
            } 

    }
    .item-has-children {
        a {
            position: relative;
        }
    }
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 100%;

}

.hr2 {
    height: 1px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
.sub-menu.selected {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    transition: transform 0.6s;  
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
```

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children");
links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('selected')) {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('selected')
    } else {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('selected')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  .dropbtn {
    background-color: $facebookBlue;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 55px;
    background: #153161;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    padding: 12px 50px;
    i {
      margin-left: 30px;
      color: #8391ab;
    }
    .arrow {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 6px solid transparent;
      border-right: 6px solid transparent;
      border-top: 6px solid #8191aa;
      margin: 100%;
      padding-top: 4px;
      z-index: 999;
    }
  }
  .dropbtn-two {
    background: $strongRed;
  }
  .dropbtn-three {
    background: $strongYellow;
  }
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 330px;
  z-index: 999;
  a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    &:hover {
      background-color: #F8F8F8
    }
  }
  .rightt {
    display: inline-block;
    // width: 9px;
    // height: 9px;
    cursor: pointer;
    // padding-left: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 9px;
      height: 9px;
      border-top: 0.2em solid #ababab;
      border-right: 0.2em solid #ababab;
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
  }
  .item-has-children {
    a {
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
}

.hr2 {
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.selected {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sass.js/0.11.0/sass.min.js" integrity="sha256-1MTlXahXbxCpbv9RxO9Qx96oBa3f1cEXH0GU4AS+TU0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-one">
            Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One  <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <div class="hr2"></div>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <div class="hr2"></div>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
          <div class="hr2"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you notice that your class name is `rightt` and not `right`? Maybe the problem is here

Comment: No, that is not problem. I am set rightt class name.

Comment: I've tried this code. Css doesn't style list properly. Can you provide full css styles? And this is not css, sass maybe?

Comment: I've included the sass.js link in the Snippet I've created from the demo; but I'm not sure it *is* Sass given the errors that're reported in the console. Please [edit] your question to include the correct library, in both the tags *and* the Snippet.

Comment: @DavidThomas
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BgVzGZ

Comment: @AlexStulov https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BgVzGZ

Comment: @AlexAI: no. Please [edit] your question to show your [mcve] code *here*, a live demo elsewhere is a nice bonus, but your relevant code needs to be in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this 
CSS:

```
.sub-menu.selected .rightt {
  float:left;    // to shift to left
  transform: rotate(180deg);   to rotate the icon
}
```

or use margin or transform using same technique

Comment: This is float my submenu. I not float submenu, i wish to float menu arrow.

Comment: Yes, but that float my submenu. ul li which is additional. I need to float Menu item One , or Menu item Two when is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children");
links.forEach((link) => {
  
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target)
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('selected')) {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('selected');
      e.target.querySelector('.rightt').classList.remove('selected');
      console.log(e.target.querySelector('.rightt'));
    } else {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('selected');
      e.target.querySelector('.rightt').classList.add('selected');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.section-two {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.section-two .header-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}
.section-two .header-holder h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Replica Regular", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #666;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .first-div-holder {
  background: brown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .first-lower-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .first-lower-div .low-lower p {
  color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .section-two .wrapper-two .first-lower-div {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-lower-div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 150px;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-lower-div h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-lower-div h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div .bottom-lower {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div .bottom-lower:nth-child(1), .section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div .bottom-lower:nth-child(2), .section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div .bottom-lower:nth-child(3), .section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div .bottom-lower:nth-child(4) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .section-two .wrapper-two .third-lower-div {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 30%;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column {
    min-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  .section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column {
    min-width: 50% !important;
  }
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column .div-column-first {
  height: 210px;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column .div-column-first img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column .div-column-first #first-child-image {
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column .div-column-first #second-child-image {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column .div-column-first #third-child-image {
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
.section-two .wrapper-two .second-div-holder .second-div-holder-div .div-column .div-column-second {
  padding: 40px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 55px;
  background: #153161;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 12px 50px;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn i {
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #8391ab;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn .arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #8191aa;
  margin: 100%;
  padding-top: 4px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn-two {
  background: red;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn-three {
  background: yellow;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 330px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
.dropdown-content .rightt {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown-content .rightt:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-top: 0.2em solid #ababab;
  border-right: 0.2em solid #ababab;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.dropdown-content .rightt.selected {
  left: 5px;
  top: 30%;
  right: auto;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.dropdown-content .left {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown-content .left:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  border-top: 0.2em solid #ababab;
  border-right: 0.2em solid #ababab;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.dropdown-content .item-has-children a {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
}

.hr2 {
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.selected {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-lower-div">
 <div class="low-lower">
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-one">
    Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One  <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>

     <div class="hr2"></div>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>

     <div class="hr2"></div>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>


 </div>
 <div class="low-lower">
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-two">
    Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>

     <div class="hr2"></div>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>

     <div class="hr2"></div>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="low-lower">
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-three">
    Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>

     <div class="hr2"></div>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>

     <div class="hr2"></div>
     <li class="item-has-children">
      <a href="#0">Main Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item One <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
       <div class="hr2"></div>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six <span class="rightt">  </span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kinospro/pen/QXxKQY

Comment: this is perfect. I voted up for this answer. Just one think, how to styling "Main Item One". I want to set padding-left when select( click on Main Item One)
I want to set margin left or padding and set text more left

Comment: If this is what you wanted you may mark it as the right answer.

Create another class and add padding-left there. Apply it on click as you did before. Or you can replace all those ".selected" classes with general one, that contains all logic you need for dropdown. And apply that class to a dropdown root.

Comment: How i can do that?